# How to decide whether to split up a VB.Net application and, if so, how to split it up?

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, architecture

I have 2 1/2 years experience of VB.Net, mostly self taught, so please bear with me if I seem rather noobish still and do not know some of the basics. I would recommend you grab a cup of tea before starting on this, as it appears to have got quite long...

I currently have a rather large application (VB.Net website) of over 15000 lines of code at the last count. It does not do retail or anything particularly complex like that - it is literally just a wholesale viewing website with admin frontend, catalogue / catalogue management system and pageview system.

I don't really know much about how .Net applications work in the background - whether they are all loaded on the same thread or if each has its own thread... I just know how to code them, or at least like to think I do... :-)

Basically my application is set up as follows:

- There are two different areas - the customer area and the administration frontend.
- The main part of the customer frontend is the Catalogue. The MasterPage will load a list of products but that's all, and this is common to all the customer frontend pages.
- I tend to work on only one or several parts of the application at a time before uploading the changes. So, for example, I may alter the hierarchy of the Catalogue and change the Catalogue page to match the hierarchy change whilst leaving everything else alone.
- The pageview database is getting really quite large and so it is getting rather slow when the application is first requested due to the way it works.
- The application timeout is set to 5 minutes - don't know how to change it, I have even tried asking this question on here and seem to remember the solution was quite complex and I was recommended not to change it, but if a customer requests the application 5 minutes after the last page view then it will reload the application from scratch. This means there is a very slow page load whenever it exceeds 5 minutes of inactivity.

I am not sure if this needs consideration to determine how best to split the application up, if at all, but each part of the catalogue system is set up as follows:

- A Manager class at the top level, which is used by the admin frontend to add, edit and remove items of the specified type and the customer frontend to retrieve a list of items of the specified type. For example the "RangeManager" will contain a list of product "Ranges" and will be used to interact with these from the customer frontend.
- An Item class, for example Range, which contains a list of Attributes. For example Name, Description, Visible, Created, CreatedBy and so on. The form for adding / editing loops through these to display relevant controls for the administrator. For example a Checkbox for BooleanAttribute.
- An Attribute class, which can be of type StringAttribute, BooleanAttribute, IntegerAttribute and so on. There are also custom Attributes (not just datatypes) such as RangeAttribute, UserAttribute and so on. These are given a data field which is used to get a piece of data specific to the item it is contained in when it is first requested. Basically the Item is given a DataRow which is stored and accessed by Attributes only when they are first requested.
- When one item is requested from a specific manager is requested, the manager will loop through all the items in the database and create a new instance of the item class. For example when a Range is requested from the RangeManager, the RangeManager will loop through all of the DataRows in the Ranges table and create a new instance of Range for each one. As stated above it simply creates a new instance with the DataRow, rather than loading all the data into it there and then. The Attributes themselves fetch the relevant data from the DataRow as and when they're first requested.

It just seems a tad stupid, in my mind, to recompile and upload the entire application every time I fix a minor bug or a spelling mistake for a word which is in the code behind (for example if I set the text of a Label dynamically). A fix / change to the Catalogue page, the way it is now, may mean a customer trying to view the Contact page, which is in no way related to the Catalogue page apart from by having the same MasterPage, cannot do so because the DLL is being uploaded.

Basically my question is, given my current situation, how would people suggest I change the architecture of the application by way of splitting it into multiple applications? I mean would it be just customer / admin, or customer / admin and pageviews, or some other way? Or not at all? Are there any other alternatives which I have not mentioned here? Could web services come in handy here? Like split the catalogue itself into a different application and just have the masterpage for all the other pages use a web service to get the names of the products to list on the left hand side? Am I just way WAY over-complicating things? Judging by the length of this question I probably am, and it wouldn't be the first time... I have tried to keep it short, but I always fail... :-)

Many thanks in advance, and sorry if I have just totally confused you!

Regards,

Richard

Comment: I think someone's probably going to give you grief for the length of this question :)

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? You mention having a website and master pages several times, but I only ever see VB.NET mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Thats why I have apologized several times and recommended getting a cup of tea before reading it! :) @Cody: I will remove the .net tag then. Give me a moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 15000 LOC is not really all that big.
2. It sounds like you are not pre-compiling your site for publishing.  You may want to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.80).aspx
3. Recompiling and uploading the application is the best way to do it.  If all you are changing is your markup, that can be uploaded individually (e.g. changing some html layout in an aspx page).
4. I don't know what you mean here by application timeout, but if your app domain recycles every 5 minutes, then that doesn't seem right at all.   You should look into this.

Also, if you find yourself working on various different parts of the site (i.e. many different changes), but need to deploy only some items in isolation, then you should look into how you are using your source control tools (you are using one, aren't you?).  Look into something like GIT and branching/merging.

Comment: With regards to point 2: Yes I am compiling it by going to Publish. Point 4: Yes I do mean the app domain recycles after about 5 minutes. The session is set to an hour but users still get logged out after 5 (luckily the only users are admin though). I will investigate this further in due course. I am afraid I am not using source control - I was under the impression, from my placement year, that this was meant for if you have a team working on it. I am the sole developer so, based on what I was told, didn't think I needed it.

Comment: Point 3: It just seems very "iffy" doing it that way. I mean unnecessary down time and alike. I always make sure that I upload at midnight or later, so as to avoid unnecessary down time, but the company is getting known world wide now so this approach won't always work.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy - use source control.  Even it it's just you - allows you to roll back if you really f*ck up.  As for the down time, if it's getting that busy, you may need to look at some kind of web farm, so you can take down individual servers at a time without disrupting too many users.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy - if 3 seems iffy, is it less iffy to upload just an aspx.vb file with a change in it ('cause you can set up your site to do this)?  What if it's relying on another change that you forgot about?  suddenly your site has compile errors...

Comment: Its not so much that it is getting busy as such, more that it is getting unpredictable. I mean sure it is fairly busy during the day, but sometimes we may have someone view 20 - 30 pages on the site at night. If one loses interest because the site is down then thats, potentially, thousands of £s lost. Mind you if they are that interested then they'll come back, won't they?

Comment: I see your point about forgetting about changes. At least uploading the entire app means that you cannot forget about any. It also allows for easy version control to just have one app.

Comment: Have accepted this as the answer on the basis that it is the most direct answer to my question. I am not sure there is a "right" answer to this question however - it depends on many factors. Also thanks for the tip about investigating the recycle time. I left that as is when I asked about it here before and was advised just to leave it be.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading:

[Application Architecture Guide](http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks. I will make sure I read through this thoroughly! It would have been useful to ask this question even if I'd only had this link in reply, to be honest.